# Permission Denied Github (push)

Tags: git, ssh, github, push, public-key

Im trying to make github work on my mac snow leopard (10.6)
I'm getting "Permission denied (publickey)." when pushing (git push -u origin master).
I've tried everything available on-line and nothing seems to solve my problem.

Could someone help me?

```
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/Filipe/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file id_rsa.pub type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Filipe/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/Filipe/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/Filipe/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/Filipe/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/Filipe/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/Filipe/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: gerve filipeximenes
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: Remote: Forced command: gerve filipeximenes
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Hi filipeximenes! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3904, received 3016 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 9975.5, received 7706.5
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Can you paste your `git remote -v`?

Comment: Sure:
origin fit@github.com:filipeximenes/first_app.git (fetch)
origin fit@github.com:filipeximenes/first_app.git (push)

I obviously have this wrong, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your github repos should look something similar to

```
origin  git@github.com:filipeximenes/a.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:filipeximenes/a.git (push)
```

This is easily acquired in the main page of your github repo if you click on ssh.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find where to change this. could you give me some instructions?

Comment: I've got it!
'git remote set-url origin git@github.com:filipeximenes/first_app.git' thanks!